# What is wrong in this calculation

Tags: exponentiation

My teacher told me that $\sqrt{x}=x^\frac{1}{2}$, but then why is this incorrect?

$$a^2+b^2=c^2$$

$$\sqrt{a^2+b^2}=c$$

$$(a^2+b^2)^\frac{1}{2}=c$$

Multiply in $\frac{1}{2}$

$$a^1+b^1=c$$

$$a+b=c$$

This seems totally correct to me, but we know that this is not the Pythagorean theorem anymore, so what is wrong?

Comment: One of the most common [mistakes](http://mathmistakes.info/facts/AlgebraFacts/learn/ctm/nlin.html).

Comment: You can't multiply powers like that $(3^2+4^2)^{1/2} = 5$ whereas $3^1 + 4^1 = 7$

Comment: Because, more generally, $(a+b)^r\ne a^r+b^r$.

Comment: Cf. [freshman's dream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freshman%27s_dream)

Answer (score 1):

In general it is not true that $(x+y)^{a} = (x^{a} + y^{a})$ for some $a$. So your argument when you jump from line 3 to line 4 is not valid.
For $a = 2$ for example, we get: $(2+5)^{2} = 7^{2} = 49$ while $2^{2} + 5^{2} = 4 + 25 = 29$.
Similarly you can show for yourself that the formula does not hold in general for $a = 1/2$.